# Composer ErrorException

Tags: php, composer-php

I installed a composer.phar file to my local directory when I run

```
 php composer.phar install
```

I get the following error:

```
  [ErrorException]                                  
  phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons
```

Is there a reason it is trying to run the phpinfo function?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a reason. I found this in the codebase:

```
    ob_start();
    phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);
    $phpinfo = ob_get_clean();
    if (preg_match('{Configure Command(?: *</td><td class="v">| *=> *)(.*?)(?:</td>|$)}m', $phpinfo, $match)) {
        $configure = $match[1];

        if (false !== strpos($configure, '--enable-sigchild')) {
            $warnings['sigchild'] = true;
        }

        if (false !== strpos($configure, '--with-curlwrappers')) {
            $warnings['curlwrappers'] = true;
        }
    }
```

It seems like Composer does not really like curl wrappers or the sigchild compile option.

Comment: Is there anyway around it?

Comment: I'd suggest not to disable `phpinfo()` on the CLI version of PHP. Note that you don't have to run Composer on the live server, you can run it on any other machine you like, with a working PHP version, and then upload everything to the live server.